# How should I save a json into my external storage?

Tags: android, json

I implemented a share button in my app. When I want to share, I can select a saved json data from the device and select via which way I want to share it (mail etc.). The problem is, that the data is NOT in the attachements. The problem is likely because I use the internal app storage. Therefore I want to save tje json data into the external storage, what would be better in my case anyway. But I am not really sure how to do that. I am not sure if I should use the Media type of content of the Documents and other files type of content which is provided by android. There is also the Appspecific files type but this looks like it is not applicaple for me, because I need to share the json data wit ha share functin. At the moment my code looks like this:

Save Function, which get's a file name I can choose myself

```
    private void saveState(String name) {
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), name + ".json");

        try{
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            MyJsonWriter writer = new MyJsonWriter();
            writer.writeJsonStream(out, ... //data structure);
            out.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("saveState ERROR", "----------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
```

LoadButtonClick Functin which shows me all files

```
 public void loadStateClick(View view) {
        final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        String[] files = MainActivity.this.fileList();
    ... //more code which is not important here
```

Load Function

```
    private void loadState(String name) {
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), name);
        InputStream in = null;
        ... //setting my data structure, not important here

        try{
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
            MyJsonReader reader = new MyJsonReader(MainActivity.this);
            SaveData savedData = reader.readJsonStream(in);
            ... // handling data structure, not important here
            in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("LOAD ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }
```